# Wordpress Plugin Development – Prevent Fatal Error

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Is there an option for preventing any fatal error which would cause the
website to go down when developing wordpress plugins?

For example, let's say there's a semicolon missing on a particular line.
Under normal circumstances, the website would be down until the plugin is either removed
or the line is fixed.

I'd like to find a way of catching every exception in the application without risking that the site may be going down, without having to put try/catch blogs around all of the code (which would be a solution, I guess).

For example, when calling the following code from a wp hook:

```
try {
    $var_does_not_exist->do_something();
}
catch (Exception $e){
    
}
```

The try/catch block doesn't seem to help in preventing the fatal error. Is there any way to fix that?

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: That's exactly what `try ... catch` is for :P I guess you're asking this because you're developing a website that's currently online? If so, then yeah it'd make sense that you don't want other people to see errors on the website. To avoid that, develop your plugin either locally and/or on a [staging website](https://wpengine.com/resources/what-is-a-staging-site-why-have-one/).

Comment: I'm looking to try out the plugin in an online environment, without risking to have the site go down due to a fatal error I didn't catch in the code (pun intended). I included an example to better explain what I'm trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really possible. Fatal errors are, as they are called fatal. It is not possible to recover from them.